# attendance system for students using Qr image contains Student ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Ok .. So i have 100 student in one class and its too hard to call everyone by his name to take attendance so i searched for easy way to make attendance automatically and i found online script [javascript] for scan qr and display it content so i will generate a qr image for every student contains his id and i will make a sql table contains some thing like

```
Table Name : Students  ----> 
- Unique Id
- Student Id
- Student Name

Table Name : subjects ----> 
- Unique Id
-Subject Code
-SUBJECT Name

Table Name : attend ----> 
- Unique Id
-Date
-Sign In : Default 0 [Absent]
-Sign Out : Default 0 [Absent]
```

so when the student scan his qr with the webcam i have .. his id will go to mysql and record attended so i can extract it as Excel file

this is qr scanner on github
http://miniqr.com/docs/demo/

will this be hard to this in php & mysql ?? please help me

Comment: And what will stop them from bringing a copy of the QR code and scanning in their friends? :)

Comment: PHP is relatively easy language to learn. Find some online tutorial and start learning it. Every PHP tutorial will include working with MySQL.

Comment: every student will come to me to scan this qr in front of me of course .. every student will scan his qr one time only ..i know its not 100% perfect method but at least will save a lot of time

Comment: Thanks   Nikolay i will .. but all this can done in php/mysql easily right ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better use of your time to be a more engaging teacher so that the students actually want to come to class?

Answer (score 0):

Each QR code can be written as a url containing your php server and the id of the student.

http://yoursitehere/yourphpscript.php?id=12345

Then on yourscript.php you simply extract the GET data and insert it into your database.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$query = "INSERT INTO `attend` (`Date`, `StudentID`) VALUES (now(),  mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])";
mysqli_query ( $link , $query);
}
```

I would recommend having your attend table simple track the student IDs of who attended, you can go back later and figure out who was absent.

Proposed structure for attend:

```
-UniqueID
-Date
-StudentID
```